# Firebug Console: Share a variable across multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firebug

Is there any way I could share variables (specifically objects) across tabs in Firefox. I know this used to work earlier but doesn't seem to work now (I am on Firefox 24).

My question is simple, lets say I open two tabs, an then go to my console and declare a variable

```
var a = {test : 1}
```

I want the variable a to be accessible in my second tab.

Comment: "I know this used to work earlier" - Hmm. I've never heard of that functionality before - is there a version that this works in (and how does it get activated)? I can see it being useful, but I can also see it being an incredibly tricky feature to implement (especially if the var is an object containing references to other objects on that page, or pieces of the DOM...)

Comment: Don't remember exactly but I believe FF was either v.17 or v.10 and Firebug was v1.10 or 1.09

Answer (score 0):

It is not (and was never) possible to share variables between different browser tabs, because they live in different [compartments](http://andreasgal.com/2010/10/13/compartments/).

What is shared between the tabs, though, is the [command history](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line#Command_History) of Firebug's Command Line. I.e. when you press <kbd>↑</kbd> on the second tab after you've executed a command in the first tab the command will appear again within the Command Line.